# Como criar um plot com dois ou mais histogramas lado a lado:

Tags: r

Eu preciso plotar esses dois histogramas um do lado do outro.

```
hist(DEM)
hist(Tdem)
```

Eu só consigo plotar individualmente.

Answer (score 3):

Existem dois modos de fazer a mesma coisa, considerando apenas o R nativo

Considere como exemplo o **dataset iris**, os dois scrits abaixo irão produzir o mesmo resultado.

o comando `c(1,2)` de ambos significa 1 linha e 2 colunas, ou seja, as duas figuras paralelas.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
hist(iris$Petal.Length)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))


split.screen(figs=c(1,2))

screen(1)
hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
screen(2)
hist(iris$Petal.Length)
close.screen(all=TRUE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]